# Converting YouTube channels to podcasts

Tags: python, django, rss, youtube

I created a Django app that converts YouTube channels to podcasts.  It uses the actual YouTube paths for the URLs.  The idea is that the user can just find the YouTube address of the desired channel (or user or playlist), then modify the domain so that the request goes to my app, and then the app will make the necessary API calls and generate the RSS.  (Right now I have it set up so that typing 'epi' right before 'youtube' in the domain will go to my app.)  It defaults to audio podcasts, but the user can get video podcasts by adding a parameter to the path.  Anyway, most of the app is just the following three Django files.  I really appreciate any help in improving speed, refactoring, renaming, improving style, etc.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.index),

    url(r'^(channel|user)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)', views.make_feed_from_channel),

    url(r'^playlist', views.make_feed_from_playlist),

    url(r'^watch$', views.handle_watch_url),

    #This is the app-generated download URL, which gets placed into the RSS and redirects to the YouTube file location
    url(r'^download/(audio|video)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
        views.download,
        name='download'),

    #This pattern handles short YouTube URLs, such as 'https://www.youtube.com/coldplayvevo'
    url(r'^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$', views.make_feed_from_custom),

]
```

views.py:

```
import email.utils
import json
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import urlopen
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
import isodate
import pafy


#Youtube API values
ENDPOINT = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/'
BASE_VIDEO_URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='
KEY = [...]

#Project landing page
HOMEPAGE = "https://amtopel.github.io/epi"


def index(request):
    """Redirect to the project homepage if there's no path in the URL."""

    return redirect(HOMEPAGE)


def make_feed_from_channel(request, id_type, id_value):
    """Create an RSS feed from a YouTube username or channel ID."""

    channel_data = get_channel_data(id_type, id_value)

    try:
        uploads_playlist_id = channel_data['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads']
    except IndexError:
        return HttpResponse('It appears that "{}" is not a valid {}.'.format(id_value, id_type))

    playlist_data = get_playlist_data(uploads_playlist_id)

    return render_feed(request, playlist_data, channel_data)


def make_feed_from_playlist(request):
    """Create an RSS feed from a YouTube playlist."""

    try:
        playlist_id = request.GET['list']
    except KeyError:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid URL.')

    try:
        playlist_data = get_playlist_data(playlist_id)
    except HTTPError:
        return HttpResponse('It appears that "{}" is not a valid playlist.'.format(request.GET['list']))

    channel_id = playlist_data['items'][0]['snippet']['channelId']
    channel_data = get_channel_data('channel', channel_id)

    return render_feed(request, playlist_data, channel_data)


def render_feed(request, playlist_data, channel_data):
    """Render the RSS feed from the playlist data,
    channel data, and desired podcast type (audio or video)."""

    video_ids = [item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'] for item in playlist_data['items']]
    videos_data = yt_api_call('videos', 'snippet,contentDetails', 'id', ','.join(video_ids))

    for item in videos_data['items']:

        #Reformat publication dates for RSS (RFC 2822)
        date_ISO = item['snippet']['publishedAt']
        parsed = parse_datetime(date_ISO)
        date_RFC = email.utils.format_datetime(parsed)
        item['snippet']['publishedAt'] = date_RFC

        #Reformat file duration for iTunes
        duration_iso = item['contentDetails']['duration']
        parsed = isodate.parse_duration(duration_iso)
        item['contentDetails']['duration'] = str(parsed)

    #Add channel data to video data to make single context
    videos_data['channel_data'] = channel_data

    #Add media type
    podcast_type = 'video' if int(request.GET.get('vid', 0)) else 'audio'
    videos_data['podcast_type'] = podcast_type

    #Add media extension
    videos_data['media_extension'] = 'mp4' if podcast_type == 'video' else 'm4a'

    return render(request, 'epi/feed.xml', videos_data)


def get_channel_data(id_type, id_value):
    """Return a dictionary of channel data from a channel id or username."""

    id_type = 'id' if id_type == 'channel' else 'forUsername'
    channel_data = yt_api_call('channels', 'contentDetails,snippet', id_type, id_value)

    return channel_data


def get_playlist_data(playlist_id):
    """Return a dictionary of playlist data from a playlist id."""

    playlist_data = yt_api_call('playlistItems', 'snippet', 'playlistId', playlist_id)
    return playlist_data


def make_feed_from_custom(request, user):
    """Handle custom URL paths like '/coldplayvevo'."""

    return make_feed_from_channel(request, 'user', user)


def handle_watch_url(request):
    """Handle '/watch?v=' urls, which may contain playlist parameters or just single videos."""

    if 'list' in request.GET:
        return make_feed_from_playlist(request)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('This appears to be just a single video.')


def download(request, media_type, video_id):
    """Redirect for media download."""

    video_url = BASE_VIDEO_URL + video_id
    video = pafy.new(video_url)

    stream = video.getbest(preftype="mp4") if media_type == 'video' else video.getbestaudio(preftype="m4a")

    redirect_url = stream.url
    return redirect(redirect_url)


def yt_api_call(path, part, id_type, id_value):
    """Make a call to the Youtube API."""

    params = {'key': KEY,
              id_type: id_value,
              'part': part,
              'maxResults': 50}

    data_url = (ENDPOINT + path + '?' + urlencode(params))

    with urlopen(data_url) as response:
        json_data = response.read()

    return json.loads(json_data)
```

feed.xml (an RSS template):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" >
    <channel>
        <title>{{ channel_data.items.0.snippet.title }}</title>
        <link>https://www.youtube.com/channel/{{ channel_data.items.0.id }}</link>
        <description>{{ channel_data.items.0.snippet.description }}</description>
        <language>en-us</language>

        <image>
            <url>{{ channel_data.items.0.snippet.thumbnails.high.url }}</url>
        </image>

        {% for item in items %}
        <item>
            <title>{{ item.snippet.title }}</title>
            <description>{{ item.snippet.description }}</description>
            <enclosure url="http://{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'download' podcast_type item.id %}.{{ media_extension }}" type="audio/mp4"/>
            <guid>http://{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'download' podcast_type item.id %}.{{ media_extension }}</guid>
            <pubDate>{{ item.snippet.publishedAt }}</pubDate>
            <itunes:duration>{{ item.contentDetails.duration }}</itunes:duration>
        </item>
        {% endfor %}
    </channel>
</rss>
```